# Using the custom made range-seekbar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

I am new to android and need help to use the range seekbar that I found earlier on stackoverflow. The problem is I am not able to get the text values in a textview on dragging the two thumbs. The desired output image is :[enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)

The url for range-seekbar is : [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)

[1](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/): [image]
Now I have done the getting the min and max value part. The next problem is having custom values for the slider in seekbar. Like i want 10000,20000,....50000,....100000.... etc. I am providing the code for my main class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // create RangeSeekBar as Integer range between 20 and 75
    RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 100000,
            getApplicationContext());
    seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar,
                Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
            // handle changed range values
            Log.i("TAG", "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue
                    + ", MAX=" + maxValue);
        }
    });

    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Val");

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    ll.addView(seekBar);
    ll.addView(tv);

    seekBar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);

    seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar,
                Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setText("Max:Min"+"\n"+minValue+" : "+maxValue);
        }
    });
```

Comment: but in this example you can see which you have added https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

Comment: I am not able to get the max and min value while dragging the thumb pointers from this example.

Comment: ok..,i see and tell you ..,

Comment: see this link you will get your full solution .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759626/listview-not-displaying-min-and-max-values-in-range-seek-bar

Comment: great at least I am done with the values part but now I am facing an issue as I want custom values to be set like 10000,20000,...50000,....10000000 like this. So the brackets shall be some thing customized. can u help ?

Comment: now show me your code ..,i have to see that..,then i will be able to understood what u want ok

Comment: provided the code now...@rajshree

Comment: do you want like this..?????  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011144/how-to-make-custom-seek-bar-in-android

Comment: Yes something like this but for the range seekbar with two thumbs...

Comment: see this link....http://www.kpbird.com/2011/05/android-seek-bar-with-two-thumb.html

Comment: the link u have provided doesn't give me the option for changing the brackets for the values which is my main problem now.

Comment: how can set progress interval in this..i meant 500,1000,1500..now according to this code if we move thum it incriment like 1,2,3..pls help

Comment: me too facing same problem..can any one suggest a solution